# User Login in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, authentication

I am using CakePHP 2.3.6. I have several plugins in a project. I want to implement the `login` system in the `UsersController`. For that, I have this code in my `AppController` :

```
public $components=array('Session','Auth');
public function beforeFilter(){
    if($this->Auth->user('role')=='admin'){
       $this->Auth->loginRedirect(array('plugin'=>'admins_panel','controller'=>'admins','action'=>'index'));
       $this->Auth->logoutRedirect(array('plugin'=>'admins_panel','controller'=>'admins','action'=>'index'));
    }
}
```

So, it means, it'll redirect me to the `Admin Panel` plugin after I login. In my `Users` controller :

```
public $components=array('Auth');
public function beforeFilter(){
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->Auth->allow();
}
public function login(){
    if($this->request->is('post')){
       if($this->Auth->login()){
          $this->Session->setFlash('Welcome '.AuthComponent::user('name'));
          $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
       }else{
          $this->Session->setFlash('Invalid username or password, please try again');
          $this->set('title_for_layout','Error - Login');
       }
    }else
       $this->set('title_for_layout','Login');
}
```

In the `User` model :

```
public $validate=array(
    'email'=>array(
        'rule'=>'isUnique',
        'message'=>'This email address has already been taken. Use another one.'
    ),
    'username'=>array(
        'rule'=>'isUnique',
        'message'=>'This username has already been taken.'
    )
);
public function beforeSave($options=array()){
    if(isset($this->data[$this->alias]['password']))
       $this->data[$this->alias]['password']=AuthComponent::password($this->data[$this->alias]['password']);
    return true;
}
```

My `View` file is :

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('User');?>
    echo $this->Form->input('username',array('type'=>'email'));?>
    echo $this->Form->input('password',array('type'=>'password'));?>
    echo $this->Form->submit('Login');
    echo $this->Form->end();
?>
```

So, I thought it'd work, but its not working. When I try to login, it says "Invalid username or password, please try again.", as I set in the "login" function.

So, what should do here ? Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: Can you also add your view, please?

Comment: I've just added the view, can you please check it out ? @SimontheSourcecoderer

Answer (score 0):

Define authentication fields in your auth component:

```
public $Components = array(
'Session',
'Auth' => array(
    'authenticate' => array(
        'Form' => array(
            'fields' => array('username' => 'username', 'password' => 'password'),
            )
        )
    )
)
```

If you want to use the `email` for your authentication then use:

```
'fields' => array('username' => 'email', 'password' => 'password')
```